# KTable aggregate forwards the same messages

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm using kafka-streams to aggregate messages into a KTable. Inside my aggregation logic, I always return the same accumulator like the following:

```
  streamOfInts
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(Accumulator.empty()) {k,v,acc -> acc}
    .toStream()
    .to(...)
```

My expectation would be that - since the value of the KTable didn't change - no value would be sent downstream. However this is not the case. The aggregate function always forwards updates.

What would be the best way to make sure updates that result in the same (or equal) value would not lead to forwards downstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSL operators emit "on update" not "on change" by design atm. There is a JIRA ticket that suggest to add "emit on change" semantics (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8770).

As a workaround, you can implement a custom `transform()` with state store -- for each input record, you check the store if it's new (-> emit and put into store) or if it changed (-> emit and update store). If it exists and did not change, don't emit anything.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's what I ended up with: one more note: I had to combine the `ValueTransformerWithKey` with a subsequent `filter` to filter out the null values that are returned by the `transform` method.